# How to align picker view title text on each row to the right?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

How can I align the title of each row in a UIPickerview to the right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement delegate's `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method and return UILabel instance from it:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UILabel* label = (UILabel*)view;
    if (view == nil){
       label= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 190, 44)];

       label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
       //Set other properties if you need like font, text color etc
       ...
    }
    label.text = [self textForRow:row forComponent:component];
    return label;
}
```

Comment: Can we use this mentod in conjunction of titleForRow:forComponent?

Comment: @Ans, sure, you can call titleForRow:forComponent: from pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: in your code. But you have to create custom label (or any other custom view) if you want to change standard rows look